# How to decide if Delphi's THeapException is heap related, not Windows GDI or something else?

Tags: delphi, exception

In Delphi's VCL class library, the EOutOfResources exception class is defined as a subclass of EOutOfMemory, which is a subclass of EHeapException, which is a subclass of the base exception class, Exception. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.EOutOfResources

The description for EOutOfResources says: "EOutOfResources is raised when an application attempts to create a Windows or widget handle and there are no more handles to allocate."

The description for EOutOfMemory says: "EOutOfMemory occurs when an application attempts to allocate dynamic memory, but there is not enough free memory in the system to meet the request."

To me, heap memory is one special case of "resource", and Windows GDI handles have very little or nothing at all to do with heap memory. Is this basically a bug and modelling error? Or is there some way to reliably know if an exception was *actually* heap-related? Have special case handling code for each and every exception type, and disregard the class hierarchy?

When handling an Exception object in an exception handler, even if it "is-a EHeapException" in a language syntactic sense, it might not be a heap related exception at all, and the corrective actions to take should be completely different. The way it looks, I cannot use the "is" statement even for dealing with VCL-originated errors, let alone third-party components which seem to be more relaxed when it comes to modelling error situations with exceptions.

Comment: Most of the times when you corrupt the heap you'll not receive any of the exception classes mentioned here. As for the exceptions that you do mention, there is no corrective action that you can take at runtime. If you encounter one, log it and terminate the process.

Comment: The question is about handling THeapException objects when you actually do encounter them. By corrective action, I meant things that the end-user or other operator can take. There happened to be an exception handler that tried to be helpful, looked at the type like, "if e is EOutOfMemory then tell the user we're out of memory", which was baloney, because it was not an out-of-memory situation in the way the coder must have thought.

Comment: You can't handle these exceptions. Once you encounter them it's game over. Log what you can, and terminate the process.

Comment: In this case it is useful if the application can help the end-user or operator to draw better-informed conclusions as to what might have happened, and what immediate workarounds might help them to get their job done, despite the error.

Comment: Right, but it's very hard to say anything that would do that with any great confidence.

Comment: Well, being able to at least tell the difference between actual out-of-heap-memory and out-of-GDI-handles would be nice, and it's unfortunate that the class hierarchy is like that. The world is full of Windows systems and applications and users who do surprising things, with varying levels of computer skills. Being able to guide the end-users with error and other messages is a way to proactively reduce and ease the handling of support incidents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hierarchy is like this:

```
EHeapException
|
|-- EInvalidPointer
|
|-- EOutOfMemory
    |
    |-- EOutOfResources
```

So you can test like this:

```
if E is EOutOfResources then
  // probably GDI resource leak
else if E is EOutOfMemory then
  // probably memory or address space is exhausted 
else if E is EInvalidPointer then
  // probably heap corruption
```

Comment: Thanks, this confirms what I thought. I ended up fixing it with just "if E.ClassType = EOutOfMemory" to get just the one exact type, and none of its subclasses.